# Typescript type to object literal

Tags: typescript

```js
type SelectData = {
  name?: boolean;
  address?: boolean;
}

const selectData: SelectData = {
  name: true
}

const untypedSelectData = {
  name: true
}
```

I want typescript to throw an error if I try to do something like this:

```js
const selectData: SelectData = {
  age: true
}
```

But I also want the type of selectData to be the same as untypedSelectData (i.e. {name: boolean})?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a compile-time check that an object is assignable to some weaker type, while also retaining a stronger inferred type for the variable or constant it's assigned to, you can use a generic identity function.

```js
function checkData<T extends SelectData>(data: T): T {
  return data;
}

// type is { name: true }
const selectData = checkData({
  name: true
})

// error: object literal may only specify known properties
const errorData = checkData({
  age: 23
})
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyhA2EDGwAiBDY6oF4oG8AoKKAO3QFsIB+ALigCMB7JxdUgbmKnQBNeAThADOwuoxZtOhAL6FCAMwCupFAEsmpKEgAWyANYYsAHgAqUCAA9gEUr2GwEyNJnQA+ABS9X9UwEpfAm4hYCUBLW8sLjlCAHpYqFBIKDUHfDJKCHpgASVoOSRNYWAoYScUI2w8XQNKjyIScips3IhZP3l4iwEBJgF6JgYAK2coeDUbAXR4KAp0EChNeAXhSCQ1BQX9UiYAdy0wXsgBYDURQkLSYu7egUrcbT0kQ1d67nQAcyyoACYAZnahCAA)

As @jcalz notes, there is a [feature request](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7481) on the official GitHub tracker for a way to do this without adding the extra function declaration and function call, but at present such a feature does not exist.

Comment: You may also want to provide a link to [microsoft/TypeScript#7481](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7481), the (probably) canonical feature request for this behavior to be supported purely at the type level (rather than needing an identity function at runtime).