# In typescript, can typing from object key value in array be defined?

Tags: typescript

I have this kind of code:

```js
type Item = { id: number; symbol: string; }

const items: Item[] = [
  { id: 1, symbol: "a"},
  { id: 2, symbol: "b" },
];
```

I wonder if typescript allows to create typing that would pick all the values from `items` array `symbol` property, like defining this but without doing it manually:

```js
type Symbols = 'a' | 'b';
```

Comment: Do I understand your question correctly: you want a way to define a type, that would always be a union of all the values of a specific property (symbol in your case) from contents of an arbitrary array defined at compile-time somewhere else in your code? So I assume the array "definition" is changing a lot, and you want to save the time to update the `type Symbols = ...`definition every time?

Comment: Yes, exactly like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot define the type from the actual array if the `const items` declaration has a type annotation, because the type annotation will be used instead of inferring a type from the actual value. If you remove the type annotation, then you can use `typeof items` to get its type, and then use [indexed access](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) to get the type of the `symbol` property.

Note that you also need to use `as const` to get the string literal types, otherwise they will be widened to just `string`.

```
const items = [
  { id: 1, symbol: "a" },
  { id: 2, symbol: "b" },
] as const;

// "a" | "b"
type Symbols = typeof items[number]['symbol']
```

Of course, this means you now aren't checking that the array elements are actually of type `Item`. To get around this, you can use the technique from [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66148407/12299000); I made the type parameter `S extends string` instead of `T extends Item` because this way the `as const` is not needed.

```
function checkItems<S extends string>(arr: (Item & {symbol: S})[]) {
  return arr;
}

const items = checkItems([
  { id: 1, symbol: "a" },
  { id: 2, symbol: "b" },
]);
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAksEFsoF4oG8oEsAmAuKAdgK4IBGEATgNxQDOIZA9gDb63AWYEDmNAvgCgBAMyIEAxsEyMCUcQAsI4gNZxEtADwBlKBAAe8Atlp0OXbgD4AFAEMKFfFbVIAZOnpNWULXwCUAbQBdX3QBKCgKCGAiClk7agFBAXEZdix4BBNUBSVVDNorfzD0LDwoAEYAGjoGUhZ8ACIbBqg+SuKMHHwAJmqPOq8G0ha2gWCqIQB6SagmloAfWeGBUEhvWpYsqFWIRmF09X9iMkpA-wByfpZzwIEgA)